# Getting user's name from email in Google Apps Domain?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I have an email from a Google Apps domain. I can see a list of all users in a domain by going into google apps' Contacts page, under 'Domain'.

If I wanted to get their full name from that email, how would I go about doing so? I've tried using `ContactsApp` to no avail. I also can't use `UserManager` in the domain tools as I don't have access to the admin tools.

Any ideas on how I could go about this?

Comment: Take a look at this [script](https://sites.google.com/a/lagaroo.com.br/dev-test/dev-test/dev-test-contacts) maybe you get an idea how to get the `contacts[1].getFullName()`.

Comment: Do any of the posts answer your question? If so please use the "tick" option to mark that response as the answer. If not, you should edit your question and clarify it so people have an opportunity to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is similar to [Google Script How do I getGivenName() of getActiveUser()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016628/google-script-how-do-i-getgivenname-of-getactiveuser), although in that case an admin was trying to create a service that a script run by members of the domain could use to get their own full names.

It's [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15628478/1677912) that might help. As a domain user, you can get the full name of people in your own contact list. Add enough people (or the right people), and your success rate will be pretty high.

Here's a modified version of that script.

```
/**
 * Get a user's name, by accessing contacts.
 *
 * @returns {String} FullName, or UserID
 *                   if record not found in contacts.
 */
function getUserName(email){
  var user = ContactsApp.getContact(email);

  // If user in contacts, return their name
  if (user) {
    // Get full name
    var name = user.getFullName();
  }
  if (!name) {
    // If not in Contacts, return the bald userID.
    name = email.split('@')[0];
  }
  return name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that.
My main problem is that this is in a Google Apps 'Directory'. It's in a specific section, and the normal ContactsApp does not pass any of these (as it encompassas <1000 users). I'd rather not go through and add a number of those to my contacts list for the sake of this, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Ask the admins to get yourself granted read only access to the provisioning API for users. That and the GAL feed are covered in the answers to this question: [How can I get read-only access to the Google Apps Profiles API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308651/how-can-i-get-read-only-access-to-the-google-apps-profiles-api/16381402#16381402)