# How can I get a user's name from their email?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm trying to get a user's name from their email and we are all on the same business domain. I saw a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008421/getting-users-name-from-email-in-google-apps-domain) detailing how to do it if you want to pull from the contacts list. The problem is when I try it myself, it knows that there is contact for me, but it returns all of the values as null. If I use another contact email, then it pulls the info just fine.

The link says that there should be another way to do it but you need admin privileges. I can get that, but all of the links to the usermanager documentation are broken. Also, searching usermanager doesn't come up with anything on Google's developer site.

```
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
Browser.msgBox(email)

var self = ContactsApp.getContact(email);
var name = self.getFullName();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Script How do I getGivenName() of getActiveUser()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016628/google-script-how-do-i-getgivenname-of-getactiveuser)

Comment: look at directory api in apps script

Comment: Ruben:  I looked at that, it seems as though the usermanager has been replaced, thanks though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With admin rights you can use the [directory api](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get#try-it). Do not forget to enhable the admin api in your appscript (Ressources > Advanced Google services) and also in the Developers Console.

```
function getUserName(email){
var result = AdminDirectory.Users.get(email, {fields:'name'});
var fullname = result.name.fullName;
Logger.log(fullname);
return fullname;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and I still get "not authorized to access this resource/api" even after enabling it in appscript and the dev console.

The bigger issue though is that if I share the sheet with someone else to run it, they get an error saying they don't have access and I can't grant them access.

The idea behind this is to update a list with someone's name when they make a change, maybe there's an easier way?

Comment: Just kidding it worked!  FYI if you add '{viewType:'domain_public'}' to the Users.get() then it will only search publicly available records and you don't need admin priveleges.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes,  '{viewType:'domain_public'}' works! Thanks @Trevor!

Answer (score 0):

If parsing from the text, you can use like below,

```
var email = "john.doe@email.com";
var name   = email.substring(0, email.lastIndexOf("@"));
console.log( name );   // john.doe
```

Hopefully help