# If and when my user put data in Column A, Column B should auto populate who the editor is in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am on google domain (G Suite). I would like to have this simple task of getting the editor/user name of a cell in column B of a spreadsheet as soon as s/he edit the cell in column A of the same row.

I have found and used a few sets of Google script, such as one below, but they didn't work unfortunately.

```
function checkEdits() {
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet1 = SS.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var specialCell = sheet1.getRange("A:A");

if (SS.getActiveCell().getA1Notation() == specialCell.getA1Notation()) {
var htmlEmail = "Cell " + specialCell.getA1Notation() + 
  " edited by " + Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
GmailApp.sendEmail("YOUR EMAIL HERE", "Spreadsheet Update " + new Date(), "", {htmlBody:htmlEmail} );
 }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `onEdit()` trigger to fire when a cell is modified, however it won't get a users email address unless they first authorise the script to allow it to get their email address. See the documentation re. [simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)

You would need to use a manual trigger i.e. a button to call the  `onEdit()` function to get the user to authorise the script(they only need to authorise the script once), then every time that user edits the sheet thereafter it will collect their email address.

Try the code below to see it in action, if you paste the code, save it and edit the sheet you will see 2 blank entries in the log. Then click the debug on the `onEdit()` function and authorise the script, it will fail as no information gets passed to `e`in debug. Edit the sheet again and check the log, now you will see that it can get your email address.

If you are an admin you can use the Admin directory to get the users name etc. using the email address.

```
function onEdit(e){
  Logger.log(e.user);
  Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
}
```

**EDIT Based on comments**

Go to 'Resources' -> 'Advanced Google services' and enable the 'Admin Directory API' and also enable it in the API console.

[image: Advanced Google Services]

[image: Admin SDK]

Paste the code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
    if (sheet == "Sheet1") {
        var sheet1 = e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
        var range = e.range;
        var getCol = range.getColumn();
        var getRow = range.getRow();

        if (getCol == 1) {
            var user = e.user.getEmail();
                var name = AdminDirectory.Users.get(user).name.fullName; // familyName, fullName or givenName
                sheet1.getRange(getRow, 2).setValue(name);
            var htmlEmail = "Cell " + range.getA1Notation() +
                " edited by " + name;
            GmailApp.sendEmail("----------", "Spreadsheet Update " + new Date(), "", {
                htmlBody : htmlEmail
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And create an onEdit trigger as shown('Edit' -> 'Current project's triggers')
[image]

Comment: Hi James! Thank you very much for your quick reply. Can you please extend your script a little more so that it considers the data in column A only, and put the ActiveUser in column B only . I tried to achieve this with my above formula in conjugation with yours, but it is not working somehow. I have given the required permissions the script asked for.

Comment: Updated as requested.

Comment: Hi James! Thank you again! That worked as expected with a little glitch though. Instead of pulling up the User name it is somehow giving the email id only. there is another post which has clearly tried to tackle that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016628/google-script-how-do-i-getgivenname-of-getactiveuser. But even that is not working. Sorry, to bother you again! :)

Comment: As I said in my original post 'If you are an admin you can use the Admin directory to get the users name etc. using the email address.' You cannot get the user's name unless you are an admin, are you an admin?

Comment: Yes, I am the admin!

Comment: Updated, NOTE: The extra steps required: Enabling the Admin directory.

Comment: Hi James! It is now neither fetching the name nor the email now. Simply blank. And i don't understand why.

Comment: @viv227295 change the line: var user = e.user to var user = e.user.getEmail();

Comment: Hi James! It is still not working even after that change. Just blank.

Comment: @viv227295 You enabled both the Admin Directory and the Admin SDK? Did you delete the trigger and recreate it to authorise the script again after adding the Admin Directory? After you edit go to 'View' -> Execution transcript, is there an error on the last line of the transcript?

Comment: Hi James! Sorry for responding late. Yea, after enabling both Admin Directory and the Admin SDK exactly as instructed by you in your updated post above, i deleted and recreated the trigger and gave the authorization. After going to 'View' -> Execution transcript, what i am getting on the last line is :  _Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code") [0.001 seconds total runtime]_ I am really not being able to understand what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you share your sheet with me? jamesd at nairongschool.com

Comment: Hi James! sorry for reverting back so late. Here is the link of the spreadsheet as asked by you (shared with you) : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15QM7z-XZEKzwatOVOnEEwpc9I63L8qnIPWBNG5H-R08/edit#gid=0