# insert my own contact details in sheet - Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-contacts-api

In our organisation we all have our contact details in Google. Often we have to make working group lists and we have to type our name and contact details manually. I wanted to make this process more efficient but only found the code to add my mail to this sheet.
Any way to add my name and phone number as well?

```
// The function below will add a custom menu item to the spreadsheet.
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();  // This line declares our first variable, the UI.
  ui.createMenu('Add me to the WGL') // This line has an action which creates a Menu called 'Add me to the WGL'
  .addItem('Add me', 'AddMe') // This line will create a sub-menu item called 'Add me' 
  .addToUi(); // This line adds the item created above to the UI
}
// The function below will take the variables declared below and plug them into our spreadsheet.
function AddMe() {
  var me = Session.getActiveUser(); // This line allows us to declare who the active user is - the person running the function.
    var actionedBy = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data").getRange('A2').setValue(me); // This line declares the cell we wish to plug our variable 'me' into.
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
     .alert('Thanks! Your details have been added to the WGL.'); // This line lets us push a popup message once the function is run.
}
```

Comment: You can store extra information in in an ascii file as JSON and parse it into an object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Script How do I getGivenName() of getActiveUser()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016628/google-script-how-do-i-getgivenname-of-getactiveuser)

Answer (score 1):

The `getActiveUser` method can only return the `emailAddress`. However, you can easily make use of the `People API` advanced service in order to retrieve the information you are looking for:

```
function AddMe() {
  var people = People.People.getBatchGet({
    resourceNames: ['people/me'],
    personFields: 'names,phoneNumbers'
  });
  var actionedBy = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data").getRange('A2').setValue('Myself: %s', JSON.stringify(people, null, 2));
}
```

Do not forget to add the advanced service in the Apps Script project by going to **Services**:

[image: People API advanced service]

#### Reference

- [Advanced People Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/people#get_the_person_for_the_user).

Answer (score 0):

I just created the file with anyfilenotepad.  You can find it in your new button in G Drive.  If it's not there then go to more and connect new apps.
Create the get the id. Put it in the code below

```
function createInfoFile() {
  const infofileid = "infofileid";
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(infofileid);
  const name = Browser.inputBox("enter name");
  const phone = Browser.inputBox("enter phone");
  const obj = { name: name, phone: phone };
  file.setContent(JSON.stringify(obj));
}


function AddMe() {
  const me = Session.getActiveUser();
  const obj = JSON.parse(DriveApp.getFileById("fileid").getBlob().getDataAsString());
  const s = `${me}\n${obj.name}\n${obj.phone}`
  const actionedBy = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Data").getRange('A2').setValue(s );
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Thanks! Your details have been added to the WGL.');

}
```